# 2 linux boxes, proxy and ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, proxy, squid

problem:
I need create ssh forwarding to other linux box that works as a proxy.

I have two linux boxes(centos 5.5), one in the office(**server1**) behind firewall, other at colocation(**server2**)

**server1** has squid proxy instaled on port **3128**.

i cant use **server1** as a direct proxy from home because its behind firewall.

iwas able to create ssh tunnel from **server1** to **server2** and 
when i log in to **server2** ican ssh root@localhost -p 12312
to **server1**

what i need is configure **server2** so it forwards port **server2**:3128 to **server1**:3128

and i could add **server2** ip addres and port to firefox proxy's and access ofice network.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

### the guess work

If I understand you correctly you want to connect from your client with a browser to server2, which then tunnels the connection to server1 and thus allows you to access the office net via the squid-proxy installed on server1.

just to get the guess work complete I think you used something like

```
server1$ ssh -R 12312:localhost:22 server2
```

to setup the first tunnel.

### a solution attempt

if you really want to be able to enter server2 as a proxy in your client's firefox settings make sure that in server2's sshd_config (/etc/ssh/sshd_config) GatewayPorts is enabled:

```
 GatewayPorts yes
```

also make sure that no blocking iptables rules are in place for the ports you want to use.

then instead of your existing tunnel you could use:

```
server1$ ssh -R *:3128:localhost:3128 server2
```

or if you really want to use your existing tunnel you could use:

```
server2$ ssh -L *:3218:localhost:3218 -p 12312 localhost
```

### some side notes

If you do it in the way explained above everyone who can reach server2 (no login required) can use port 3128 as proxy port and thus access your office net (if no other measures are in place)

I don't know what kind of policies exist in your company but before attempting such tunnels make sure you don't break any.

### another solution

change your existing tunnel to

```
server1$ ssh -R 3128:localhost:3128 server2
```

from your client issue a

```
client$ ssh -L 3218:localhost:3128 server2
```

then in your firefox add localhost and port 3128 as proxy config.

like this you don't need the configuration of GatewayPorts and only people with a login on server2 can use the tunnel to server1

Comment: Congrats on figuring out the question :-)

Comment: +1 for this answer :)

Comment: did it solve your problem?